# Debugging native crashes in iOS in react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am building an iOS app using react-native. I am distributing the app using TestFlight. Every once in a while, I would see a crash reported on TestFlight. When I look at the crash info in Xcode, it doesn't tell anything about what part of JS code may have caused the crash. Below is a sample crash log I get on Xcode. Here `App` refers to my app name.

[image]

Since these crashes occur only intermittently, and the above stack trace points to very generic methods, I am not sure how to go about debugging such crashes.

Please share what would be a good strategy to debug these crashes.